# How to deploy qt applications in raspberrypi 4

Tags: linux, deployment, qt5, raspberry-pi4, appimage

i want deploy qt applications in raspberrypi and share apps with other raspberrypi without instal qt. As an executable file. I tried linuxdeployqt but it error "./linuxdeployqt-continuous-x86_64.AppImage: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" when run AppImage. Can anyone help me? I am using Qt version 5.11

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using appimage-builder. You will have to install it using pip3 in your raspberry pi, also it's recommended to use Raspbian (this is where I test it)

Check the [appimage-builder documentation](https://appimage-builder.readthedocs.io/) for more details.